# How to build a form in angular such that it on submission it returns the array having same input names

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular7

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit(feedbackForm)" #feedbackForm="ngForm">
     <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let ques of questions;">
          <label for="comment">{{ques.question}}</label>
          <textarea 
           class="form-control"
           rows="5"
           id = "comment"
           name="feedbackAnswers"
           ngModel
           required>
          </textarea>
     </div>
          <button 
          type="submit" 
          class="btn btn-info" 
          *ngIf=!sendingEmail
          [disabled]="!feedbackForm.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

on ,
console.log(feedbackForm),
 the 'values' property only shows first input. How can I get an array having name i.e 'feedbackAnswers' and having value what use did input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `name` attribute unique so that the template driven form will create a control for each input in the loop... try the following change. `[name]="ques.question"`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit(feedbackForm)" #feedbackForm="ngForm">
     <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let ques of questions;">
          <label for="comment">{{ques.question}}</label>
          <textarea 
           class="form-control"
           rows="5"
           id = "comment"
           [name]="ques.question"
           ngModel
           required>
          </textarea>
     </div>
          <button 
          type="submit" 
          class="btn btn-info" 
          *ngIf=!sendingEmail
          [disabled]="!feedbackForm.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How can I implement reactive form here?